# Low-pass filtering and computing integral spectral power of non-uniformly sampled data

Tags: power-spectral-density, lowpass-filter, nonuniform

I'm not too experienced in signal processing, so I apologise in advance if I get some of the basics wrong.

I have some data (human behaviour) collected over multiple months. The data is sampled non-uniformly, with intervals between individual datapoints ranging between milliseconds to hours. Also, there is no data available during the night, because the said human is asleep.

I am interested in learning how much of the variance in the data is explained by fast vs slow frequencies. Please correct me if I am wrong, but I would guess this is strongly related to if not equivalent to asking what is the relative fraction of the integral of the power spectrum only over sufficiently low frequencies?

So I would like to try a few cutoffs, like 1h, 1day, 1week, 1month, see how much relative spectral power is contained in all frequencies above cutoff, and also plot the low-pass-filtered curve to see if I can learn some patterns from it.

So, if my data was uniformly-sampled, I suspect that a decent estimate would be to numerically compute the power spectrum and sum all values before and after the said threshold and compute their ratio. Further, I could inverse-transform the thresholded fourier series to get the LPF, or just use an existing filter routine such as butterworth.

However, the challenge is that the data is non-uniformly sampled. I see two approaches: either attempt to compute LPF and power directly on non-uniform data, or to bin the data and compute the above quantities on the binned data.

If the first approach is possible, please suggest how I could proceed. I am aware that power spectrum estimators, such as via naive fourier-transform or the more advanced Lomb-Scargle are suitable for periodicity detection, but do not really give any guarantees about meaningful integrals as far as I know. Further, I would not know how to get the low-pass-filtered curve afterwards.

The second approach may be a bit easier. I could bin my data to 1 minute bins (I don't care for finer resolution), and then do the low-pass-filtering as for uniform data. There are two problems however. Firstly, some of the bins will have NAN values in them, as they will correspond to zero datapoints. Is there a way to perform such analysis on uniform data that does have multiple NAN values? Secondly, some bins will have more datapoints than others. Is there a way (or any reason) to integrate variance estimates for every bin into the analysis?

**EDIT**: The current, slightly brutal solution I have come up with is as follows.

1. I introduce a piecewise-constant model of timestep size $T$.
2. I fit this model to data using least squares. That means for each piece selecting the mean of all data points that land within it. Any bins that have zero datapoints landing in them are ignored
3. I compute the coefficient of determination R2 as the ratio of the variance explained by the model and the total variance of the data. Again, the pieces that have no datapoints landing in them are ignored during R2 calculation.
4. I make a coarse assumption that this model is the low-pass-filter of the original data at frequency threshold $f \approx 1/T$. Not very accurate, but likely good enough.
5. The above R2 is biased, since even purely random data would have some explained variance. Thus I repeat the procedure multiple times, shuffling the data values across timesteps, and plot the shuffled R2. By sweeping over different $T$ I get pictures like the following.

[image]

The only difficulty is that the piecewise-constant model may be a bit coarse, and thus likely a has a bias in estimation of the cutoff frequency. Perhaps the optimal solution in terms of least-squares formulation would be to find the function that best fits the data from the class of all possible functions for which the power spectrum is exactly zero for all values below the cutoff. That sounds intimidatingly hard though. Perhaps I will try splines at some point, they seem to have some guarantees in terms of uniform smoothness.

Comment: The sampling period (or frequency) is closely tied with the timescale of the phenomenon you are trying to observe. If the sampling period extends into the hours, then this means that the phenomenon you are oberving evolves slowly (?). If that is the case, you can either use interpolation to "mimick" regular sampling or fit a model of the phenomenon to the data and sample it's output. The answers to the rest of the questions would also follow from this.

Comment: @A_A Whether the phenomenon evolves slowly or not is exactly what I would like to quantify. I have in fact multiple different variables recorded, and I would like the check which ones are changing slowly, and which ones are changing fast, and by how much. Interpolation is not an option, as it would artificially boost autocorrelation